# VB.NET Dynamically update items lists in combo boxes based on other selected items

Tags: vb.net, function, combobox, datasource

The intended functionality of my code:
I may have many intertwined comboboxes with datasources which means that a combobox items list may be dependant on the selected items in one or multiple other comboboxes. Upon any one selectedinedex / item change it needs to refresh all the items lists in all comboboxes and if previously selected item is present in the new items list then select it, else select nothing. It also must avoid entering an endless loop.

The complete code with 3 comboboxes as I have it so far:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Public List_LowerFilmWidth As New List(Of Integer)
    Public List_LowerFilmType As New List(Of String)
    Public List_UpperFilmWidth As New List(Of Integer)

    Public intLowerFilmWidth As Integer
    Public intUpperFilmWidth As Integer
    Public strLowerFilmType As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Arrays
        Load_Datasources()

        'ComboBox_LowerFilmWidth
        With ComboBox_LowerFilmWidth
            .DataSource = List_LowerFilmWidth
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With

        'ComboBox_LowerFilmType
        With ComboBox_LowerFilmType
            .DataSource = List_LowerFilmType
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With

        'ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth
        With ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth
            .DataSource = List_UpperFilmWidth
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With

    End Sub

    Sub Load_Datasources()

        'LowerFilmWidth
        With List_LowerFilmWidth
            .Clear()
            For i = 320 To 1200
                .Add(i)
            Next i
        End With

        'LowerFilmType
        With List_LowerFilmType
            .Clear()
            .Add("Flexible")
            .Add("Rigid")
        End With

    End Sub

    Sub Refresh_Datasources()

        'UpperFilmWidth
        List_UpperFilmWidth = Get_List_UpperFilmWidth(intLowerFilmWidth, strLowerFilmType)
        ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth.DataSource = List_UpperFilmWidth

    End Sub

    Function Get_List_UpperFilmWidth(LowerFilmWidth As Integer, LowerFilmType As String) As List(Of Integer)

        Dim UpperFilmWidth As New List(Of Integer)

        Select Case LowerFilmType
            Case "Flexible"
                UpperFilmWidth.Add(LowerFilmWidth - 5)
                UpperFilmWidth.Add(LowerFilmWidth - 15)
            Case "Rigid"
                UpperFilmWidth.Add(LowerFilmWidth)
                UpperFilmWidth.Add(LowerFilmWidth - 5)
        End Select

        Return UpperFilmWidth

    End Function

    Private Sub ComboBox_LowerFilmWidth_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_LowerFilmWidth.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SelectedItemChanged(intLowerFilmWidth, CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem) Then
            intLowerFilmWidth = CInt(CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem)
            Refresh_Datasources()
            CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem = intLowerFilmWidth
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_LowerFilmType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_LowerFilmType.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SelectedItemChanged(strLowerFilmType, CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem) Then
            strLowerFilmType = CStr(CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem)
            Refresh_Datasources()
            CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem = strLowerFilmType
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SelectedItemChanged(intUpperFilmWidth, CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem) Then
            intUpperFilmWidth = CInt(CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem)
            Refresh_Datasources()
            CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem = intUpperFilmWidth
        End If
    End Sub

    Function SelectedItemChanged(Old_Value As Object, New_Value As Object) As Boolean
        Return (CStr(Old_Value) <> CStr(New_Value))
    End Function

End Class
```

So the logic now is that whenever any index is changed in any combobox then it refreshes the datasource of ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth. Comparing if the selected item in a particular comboboex was actually changed helps avoid endless loop.

At the moment there are two problems:

1. Whenever changing the selected item of ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth it selects it back to the first item.
2. If previously selected item is present in the new list - it doesn't select it.

How do I make such centralized logic where combobox items lists adjust to the new criteria based on selected items in  other comboboxes?

**STATUS UPDATE:**
From what I understand that bindingsource must be teh dataource type that updates the combobox.datasource without resetting it which means the following code should work to populate ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth, but it doesn't:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Public List_LowerFilmWidth As New BindingSource
    Public List_LowerFilmType As New BindingSource
    Public List_UpperFilmWidth As New BindingSource

    Public intLowerFilmWidth As Integer
    Public intUpperFilmWidth As Integer
    Public strLowerFilmType As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Arrays
        Load_Datasources()

        'ComboBox_LowerFilmWidth
        With ComboBox_LowerFilmWidth
            .DataSource = List_LowerFilmWidth
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With

        'ComboBox_LowerFilmType
        With ComboBox_LowerFilmType
            .DataSource = List_LowerFilmType
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With

        'ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth
        With ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth
            .DataSource = List_UpperFilmWidth
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With

    End Sub

    Sub Load_Datasources()

        'LowerFilmWidth
        With List_LowerFilmWidth
            .Clear()
            For i = 320 To 1200
                .Add(i)
            Next i
        End With

        'LowerFilmType
        With List_LowerFilmType
            .Clear()
            .Add("Flexible")
            .Add("Rigid")
        End With

    End Sub

    Sub Refresh_Datasources()

        'UpperFilmWidth
        List_UpperFilmWidth = Get_List_UpperFilmWidth(intLowerFilmWidth, strLowerFilmType)

    End Sub

    Function Get_List_UpperFilmWidth(LowerFilmWidth As Integer, LowerFilmType As String) As BindingSource

        Dim UpperFilmWidth As New BindingSource

        Select Case LowerFilmType
            Case "Flexible"
                UpperFilmWidth.Add(LowerFilmWidth - 5)
                UpperFilmWidth.Add(LowerFilmWidth - 15)
            Case "Rigid"
                UpperFilmWidth.Add(LowerFilmWidth)
                UpperFilmWidth.Add(LowerFilmWidth - 5)
        End Select

        Return UpperFilmWidth

    End Function

    Private Sub ComboBox_LowerFilmWidth_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_LowerFilmWidth.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SelectedItemChanged(intLowerFilmWidth, CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem) Then
            intLowerFilmWidth = CInt(CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem)
            Refresh_Datasources()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_LowerFilmType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_LowerFilmType.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SelectedItemChanged(strLowerFilmType, CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem) Then
            strLowerFilmType = CStr(CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem)
            Refresh_Datasources()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_UpperFilmWidth.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SelectedItemChanged(intUpperFilmWidth, CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem) Then
            intUpperFilmWidth = CInt(CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem)


        End If
    End Sub

    Function SelectedItemChanged(Old_Value As Object, New_Value As Object) As Boolean
        Return (CStr(Old_Value) <> CStr(New_Value))
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Not really completely sure we've got all the info sorry, could be wrong but there are bits of your code that suggest an element data binding going on as well which isn't shown in the code.  First thing I would suggest is good and proper debug.  Make sure the events are triggering when expected and values are being calculated correctly.  Next, I would recommend actually using Databindings to backing properties, this will to a degree help separate the logic from the UI meaning you can avoid all the type casting on controls your doing now.

Comment: I literally posted the entire code code except for comboboxes and form creation which is written automatically when you create them in designer. The question is about the approach and logic to create a form of comboboxes where items lists of each might be dependant on another combobox/es selected items. The logic that avoids rewriting the same logic under each combobox but rather centralizing the entire thing

Comment: I've red about bindingsources but to my experience with it - it's no different than list(of)... I wasn't able to reflect changes in bindingsource in the combobox without resetting it again and I guess it's a big point to make this problem work

Comment: Hi, didn't say bindingsources, suggested look at databindings.  Two different quite different things.  DataBinding allow you to Bind a property of your control to a variable (For example the Value) which when done properly will simplify your logic.  DataBinding can also be set at the UI (which your code doesn't show)